# Why DIV does not follow the parent's attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider this snipped code

```
<fieldset id="fieldset">
    <input id="first" />
    <div id="second" />
</fieldset>
```

and

```
$('#fieldset').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
console.log($('#first').is(':disabled'))
console.log($('#second').is(':disabled'))
```

and the output is

```
true
false
```

I noticed that the input tag follows the parent's attribute and also I think all the tags that has widget follows but others such as div,a,span or .. does not.

why?

and if I want div element follows the parent's attribute what should I do?

Comment: Disabled only works for form elements.

Comment: `div` does not have property called as **disabled**, what are you trying to achieve by disabling a div ?

Answer (score 5):

The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls:-the-disabled-attribute) says:

> A form control is disabled if its disabled attribute is set, or if it is a descendant of a fieldset element whose disabled attribute is set and is not a descendant of that fieldset element's first legend element child, if any.

The div isn't disabled because it isn't a form control. It can't be disabled because being so would be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

So if you for some reason would like to check if the `fieldset` an element is in is disabled, you could create a custom function for this:

```
$.fn.isInDisabled = function () {
    var x;
    if($(this).is('fieldset')) {
       // If this is a fieldset, use it.
       x = $(this);
    }
    else {
        // Otherwise use the closest ancestor that is.
        x = $(this).parents('fieldset');
        // Return true if we are not in a fieldset.
        if(!x.length) return true;
    }
    // Return wheater x is disabled or not.
    return x.is(':disabled');
}
```

Or, if you don't bother with the case where we are not in a fieldset, you could use:

```
$.fn.isInDisabled = function () {
    return ($(this).is('fieldset') ? $(this) : $(this).parents('fieldset')).is(':disabled');
}
```

That will return `false` if we are not in a fieldset.